# Communication between activities

Tags: android, imageview, android-activity

I have an activity lets say activity A.

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{
static int id_original;
.
.
.
id_original = R.drawable.afra_o;
}
```

afra_o is the ImageView of another activity's layout. Lets say Activity B. In activity A, i want to set id_original to some drawable and then I want to change ImageView of B by referencing id_original in activity B.

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
ImageView view_correct = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_original);
view_correct.setImageResource(ActivityA.id_original);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_B);
```

Like this one. But I got errors like this one

```
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    activity      ComponentInfo{com.example.turkishlogoquiz/com.example.turkishlogoquiz.CorrectActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at com.example.turkishlogoquiz.CorrectActivity.onCreate(CorrectActivity.java:20)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-06 11:57:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(10791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
```

Any help, please.

Comment: When do you set the value of id_original in your activity A ? is your activity B always started after Activity A ? Also in your stack trace does "CorrectActivity" correspond to your activityA or ActivityB ?

Comment: @ocry, have you defined both the activities in AndroidManifest.xml file ?

Comment: I set in onCreate in Activity A. Yes activity B is always started after A. CorrectActivity is B.

Comment: @Jacob yes both are defined. If I remove setImage of the view, it runs normally.

Comment: @ocry, then please upload the code of both  the activities

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `ImageView view_correct = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_original);` returns null pointer. You can not call a `findViewById()` before you set content view by calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_B);`.

Check this out : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

- onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(int) with a layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I handled the question. I used intent.putExtra to pass data from one activity to another. By using it, I manage to set image of Activity B according to Activity A dynamically. Thank you for the answers.